# How do I blit text letter by letter in pygame? (like in those retro RPG games)

Tags: python, time, pygame

I set up collision with NPCs such that a dialogue appears when the player goes near them but I decided to change it because it'll look more retro if the text is rendered letter by letter, I tried to 'blit' it each letter and add `time.sleep(1)` between each letter but that slowed down the game substantially when it was executed. Is there any other way to do this? I have attached the dialogue function from my code and my entire code is linked [here](https://github.com/Batsy24/pokemon-game.git).

```
def npc_one_dialogue():
    P = font.render('P', True, black)
    r = font.render('r', True, black)
    o = font.render('o', True, black)
    f = font.render('f', True, black)
    e = font.render('e', True, black)
    s = font.render('s', True, black)
    scr.blit(P, (110, 420))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    scr.blit(r, (140, 420))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    scr.blit(o, (170, 420))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    scr.blit(f, (200, 420))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    scr.blit(e, (230, 420))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    scr.blit(s, (260, 420))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    scr.blit(s, (290, 420))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    scr.blit(o, (320, 420))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    scr.blit(r, (350, 420))
```

Comment: You can just decrease the amount it sleeps to something like 0.2 seconds... Does it impact the overall game, or just the dialogue? If your problem is still there, try uploading the code because there may be another problem

Comment: @Shufi123 keeping the sleep value as 1 or 0.2 either way it slows down so much that it doesn't even give the desired effect and the entire game gets slowed down, not even the key events are executed fast enough they get executed like 5 seconds late and not even completely as for the code ill edit it and add the dialogue function part of it right now and add an GitHub link to the entire thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what we need is a timer. But before that, the way you are rendering every letter manually is very tedious. We can put that in a loop so that every iteration we render one letter.

One way of doing this is to generate individual text surface for every single letter and store them in `surfaces` list. After that we need to know where we want to blit every letter. We can iterate through the surfaces and add positions accordingly to `positions` list.

```
FONT = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), 20)
previousWidth = 0
def getSurfaces(word, pos):
    global previousWidth
    
    surfaces = []
    positions  = []
    for i in range(len(word)):
        surf = FONT.render(f"{word[i]}", True, black)
        surfaces.append(surf)
    for i in range(len(surfaces)):
        previousWidth += surfaces[i-1].get_rect().width
        positions.append([previousWidth + pos[0], pos[1]])
    return surfaces, positions
```

The function returns a surface and position for every letter in the word. First position in the `positions` list relating to the first letter, second to the second letter etc, so it is easy to loop and blit them like this:

```
    for i in range(len(surfaces)):
        src.blit(surfaces[i], (positions[i][0], positions[i][1]))
```

Working minimal example:

```
import time
import pygame
pygame.init()

D = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))
FONT = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), 20)

black = (0, 0, 0)
word = "profes"
   
previousWidth = 0
def getSurfaces(word, pos):
    global previousWidth
    
    surfaces = []
    positions  = []
    for i in range(len(word)):
        surf = FONT.render(f"{word[i]}", True, black)
        surfaces.append(surf)
    for i in range(len(surfaces)):
        previousWidth += surfaces[i-1].get_rect().width
        positions.append([previousWidth + pos[0], pos[1]])
    return surfaces, positions

surfaces, positions = getSurfaces(word, [100, 150])

def npc_one_dialogue():
    for i in range(len(surfaces)):
        D.blit(surfaces[i], (positions[i][0], positions[i][1])) 

while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    D.fill((255, 255, 255))

    npc_one_dialogue()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Now that we have a way to individually render every letter, the problem just becomes about adding a delay between rendering each letter, which can be done using `time.time`. So we can change the `npc_one_dialogue` function to:

```
start = time.time()
count = 0
def npc_one_dialogue(delay=0.3):
    global count
    global start
    now = time.time()
    if count < len(surfaces):
        if now - start > delay:
            count += 1
            start = now
    for i in range(count):
        D.blit(surfaces[i], (positions[i][0], positions[i][1]))
```

Comment: @pythonnewbie Your welcome. Also, I somehow managed to delete a line of code when i copied the code from my IDLE to  here, so the minimal "working" example wasn't working. I changed it now though, so it actually works.